# Run Script after pause EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need running a (bash)Script after each start from my EC2.
The machine stops 90% a day - after wake up - a script should run.

I tried to push it in the USER-DATA - but this only runs on init.
After this I followed up here: https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/
but this didn't also work - because to stop a machine and start a machine seems to be no reboot

I also implement a simple output in the rc.local but also: nothing happens.
Is there a way?
So we talk to switch from this Instance-State

[image]

to this:

[image]

Comment: " to stop a machine and start a machine seems to be no reboot" - this isn't my experience

Answer (score 2):

You could use the oneshot feature of systemd

Write scripts for mystart.sh and mystop.sh, chmod/chown them

/etc/systemd/system/mystart.service. Note that we must specify RemainAfterExit=true so that systemd considers the service as active after the setup action is successfully finished.

```
[Unit]
Description=mystart
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mystart.sh
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/mystop.sh
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reload the systemd (systemctl reload) and try stopping and starting to test it

Answer (score 0):

Cloud-Init (which runs the User Data script on first boot) can also run scripts:

- On every boot
- On the next boot only

So, simply install your script in this directory:

```
/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/
```

Each time the instance is booted (started), the script will run. This is a great way to trigger a batch process on the instance.

See also: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)